Properties of a "generalised" little-o notation
According to Wikipedia, the little-o notation is defined this way: $f(x) = o(g(x))$ as $x\to\infty$ if for all $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ |f(x)| \le \varepsilon g(x) \quad \text{whenever } x\ge N. $$
Little-o notation becomes very useful in analysis once we combine it with its properties:

If $f=o(h)$, then $\alpha f = o(h)$, where $\alpha$ is a constant.
If $f=o(\alpha h)$, then $f = o(h)$.
If $f=o(F)$ and $g=o(G)$, then $f\cdot g = o(F\cdot G)$.
If $f=o(g)$ and $g=o(h)$, then $f=o(h)$.

I know the definition was originally used to investigate asymptotic behaviour of functions, but thought it felt a bit limiting, so I wonder if we can make the following generalisation of the notation and get similar properties:
Write $f = \bar{o}(g)$ as $x\to x_0$, where $x_0\in \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \pm\infty \}$, if for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
$$ |f(x)| < \varepsilon g(x) \quad \text{whenever } |x-x_0|<\delta . $$
If this doesn't have some of the above properties, what other useful properties can we derive out of the definition?

It seems that the only difference is in the location of the limit. If so: yes, the little-$o$ notation is already defined and used for all possible location limits—after all, $f(x)=o(g(x))$ is exactly the same statement as $\lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$.
